# WPF Datagrid not taking up all available remaining space

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridtextcolumn

I have a WPF DataGrid and no matter what I try it won't resize to fit the available space. In my Window there is a lot of empty space to the right and I want the columns to change their width  according to the space available.

The code I have for the Datagrid is:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="ResultDataGrid" Margin="40,30,6,6" Grid.Row="1"  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Records}" Background="Transparent"   HeadersVisibility="Column" IsReadOnly="true" CanUserSortColumns="False"  LostFocus="ResultDataGrid_LostFocus" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top">

        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="ColumnHeader_Click" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsCheck,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Click="CheckBox_Click"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DeviceSNDataGridText" Binding="{Binding InsCCode}" 
                                Header="{StaticResource DeviceSNString}"  FontSize="14"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DataTimeDataGridText" Binding="{Binding Created}" 
                                Header="{StaticResource DateTimeString}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ModeDataGridText" Binding="{Binding Mode}" 
                                Header="{StaticResource ModeString}"  FontSize="14" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ResultDataGridText" Binding="{Binding Result}" 
                                Header="{StaticResource ResultString}"  FontSize="14"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ScanIndexDataGridText" Binding="{Binding ScanIndex}"
                                Header="{StaticResource ScanIndexString}"  FontSize="14" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

After reading online, I tried setting each **DataGridTextColumn** width to * but that gave me this resulting datagrid below:

[image]

I also tried setting the ColumnWidth on the Datagrid itself to * but it also gave the same result as the picture above.

By the way, my datagrid is contained within a grid (on **Row 1**)  which is defined like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

What am I missing? Any suggestions please?

Comment: Try without the HorizontalAlignment

Comment: @the.Doc I tried that before but that would just give me an empty column at the end which will take up all available space. I don't want that. That's why I have HorizontalAlignment="Left"

Comment: Ok, in that case set the column widths to Auto instead of *

Comment: @the.Doc I tried that already.  "Auto means that a column is given as much width as the elements within it require."  That will not fix the issue.

Comment: Do you want the columns to fill the available width and be spaced evenly? If so, remove the HorizontalAlignment and use * sizing on all columns. If you want each column to size to its content and be left aligned, keep the HorizontalAlignment and use Auto sizing.

Comment: @the.Doc Yes. I want the columns to fill the available width and be spaced evenly. But, when I remove HorizontalAlignment and set each column width to * , the columns all become squished together like the picture above. The only difference is that there is an empty column at the end which takes up all the available space.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239734/discussion-between-kafka-and-the-doc).

Comment: @Kafka: Could you please provide a full reproducible example including the a parent window?

Comment: Please create a minimal example that reproduces the issue. This way you may be able to solve the issue while creating the example. What you want is the default behavior. So a parent control must change the layout behavior. If you don't provide this minimal example, nobody can help you.

Comment: @mm8  Hello, it seems like the issue was with ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True".    When I set it to false and set each DataGridTextColumn width to *, the datagrid takes up all the available space.

Comment: @mm8 And when I maximize the window the Datagrid columns increase in width to take up all the available space, which is what I wanted. But weirdly enough, then when I minimize the Window again, the datagrid does not resize and remains at its full width and therefore a horizontal scrollbar appears on the grid.  Does anyone know why that is happening?